# Apache mod_wsgi installation error

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, python, mod-wsgi

I'm running CentOS 6.7, I'm trying to install mod_wsgi (https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/)

Normally I'd just do:

> yum install mod_wsgi

But since I need to make sure it compiles under Python 2.7 (as opposed to CentOS default Python 2.6 version), I decided to download the repo (https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases) and make sure it's configured for my scenario.

For the installation, I followed the the office guide: https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide

The only difference is that I changed the Python version:

```
./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

The above returns:

```
checking for apxs2... no
checking for apxs... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for prctl... yes
checking Apache version... ./configure: line 2765: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 2765: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 2766: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 2769: /: is a directory

./configure: line 2964: apxs: command not found
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
```

Running make returns:

```
apxs -c -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -DNDEBUG  -Wc,-g -Wc,-O2  src/server/mod_wsgi.c src/server/wsgi_*.c -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config  -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
/bin/sh: apxs: command not found
make: *** [src/server/mod_wsgi.la] Error 127
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I was missing the Apache dev tools:

yum install httpd-devel

Comment: Can you set your question as answered ? thanks

Comment: have same problem ? can i know how can i fix it ?